# SQL - OR causes query to run extremely slow

Tags: sql, asp.net, .net, sql-server, database

When I combine two conditions in the WHERE clause of my query, it takes well over a minute to run. If I split into two different queries, they both run in about 1 second.

Any thoughts? See below:

This takes well over a minute

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(b.BookKey)
from
    Books b (nolock)
    inner join BookPublishCities bp (nolock)
        on b.BookKey = bp.BookKey
where
    contains(bp.PublishRegionName, @SearchTerm) OR contains(b.BookTitle, @SearchTerm)
```

Together these are about 1 second

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(b.BookKey)
from
    Books b (nolock)
    inner join BookPublishCities bp (nolock)
        on b.BookKey = bp.BookKey
where
    contains(bp.PublishRegionName, @SearchTerm)

-- and...

SELECT 
    COUNT(b.BookKey)
from
    Books b (nolock)
    inner join BookPublishCities bp (nolock)
        on b.BookKey = bp.BookKey
where
    contains(b.BookTitle, @SearchTerm)
```

- There is a full-text index on Books.BookTitle and BookPublishCities.PublishRegionName.
- Both tables contain about 500k rows. Reason I didn't include PublishRegionName in Books table is because you're only allowed one full-text index per table.
- There is an index on BookPublishCities.BookKey

I'm just not sure why separate queries are so much faster. Thoughts?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Server full-text search performance dramatically down when using "OR" in where clause](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4100589/sql-server-full-text-search-performance-dramatically-down-when-using-or-in-whe)

Comment: Thanks @rtumaykin. Are you able to provide any elaborate on the 2nd answer in that post? "The real problem is that with the "OR" in place, a proper index cannot be chosen as the "correct" index would depend on the outcome of the first evaluation for every single row. Therefor, the DBMS selects one index (most probably the correct one for the first part of the "OR") and, in case the first evaluation comes back as "false", runs the second one unindexed. This makes it slow. The performance for this greatly depends on how often the first evaluations returns as "false"."

Comment: Without seeing the execution plans there is really not much to guess. Optimizer tries to pick a balance between an optimal execution plan and not wasting too much time on building it. I can think of 3 possible issues:
1. Optimizer gives up on the OR and resorts to a full table scan
2. Optimizer has a cached execution plan that was created based on the @SearchTerm that was legitimately faster to execute using a full scan, and now it is just reusing it
3. Optimized decided that the cost of the OR exceeds the parallelism threshold and tries to run the query using multiple parallel threads.

Comment: If you can capture the execution plans and post them here I can give you more details. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190646.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`or` can pose a problem for SQL optimizers.  Usually, this problem arises with `join` conditions, but it may also be happening here.  Try using `union` and see if this is faster:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM ((SELECT bookkey
       FROM BookPublishCities bp (nolock)
       WHERE contains(bp.PublishRegionName, @SearchTerm)
      ) UNION ALL
      (SELECT BookKey
       FROM Books b (nolock)
       WHERE contains(b.BookTitle, @SearchTerm)
      )
     ) b;
```

Note that I simplified the subqueries.  The `join`s don't seem necessary given the logic -- although under some circumstances they might be important (for instance, if the joins are used for filtering because book keys are not in both tables).

This also might not return exactly the same results, because presumably a title and a region could both match.  This could also generate duplicates in your query, so you might want `count(distinct)` in the outer query.

Comment: thanks. FYI the reason I included the inner joins in the separate queries was to illustrate the fact that all I had to do was remove the OR conditions in order to significantly increase speed

Comment: I'm a bit new to SQL. In terms of best practices and readability I would have thought OR would be a preferred choice. I just can't get it to run as quick as the UNION queries. Is this a common occurrence?

Comment: @Ricky . . . It sometimes occurs.  SQL is a pretty useful language and the optimizers are quite reasonablel, but they don't catch everything.

Comment: Thanks. It looks like UNION is the way to go for me. Although, I still don't  understand what makes OR slower. In the post suggested by @rtumaykin, an explanation is given, but I do not understand it. Something about not being about to choose a "proper" index?

Comment: Here is the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4100589/sql-server-full-text-search-performance-dramatically-down-when-using-or-in-whe

Comment: @Ricky  . . .  SQL optimizers are pretty good.  People are still smarter.  They miss some things that are obvious to us.

Answer (score -2):

`Set SHOWPLAN_ALL on`. Inspect the plan for the combination and compare it to the individuals. You may need to provide some hints to the QEP

Comment: Query hints (including and especially `NOLOCK`) should only be used as an absolute last resort and only if you know exactly what you're doing.

Comment: Does nolock cause the query to slow down?